# I got stuck in the mountains and it is a very cold winter....Will I survive if I do something like this?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, temperature, electromagnetic-induction

I got stuck in the mountains and it is a very cold winter. Will I survive if I do the action shown on the picture? I start rotating a permanent magnet about an axis near a thick iron plate and wait to see if the eddy currents in the iron heat up that piece of metal.
[image: 1]

How much can the temperature of a piece of conductive material increase from the eddy currents produced by a rotating magnet?

Answer (score 2):

You are likely to generate more heat in your muscles than would be generated in the iron.  But that would be using up the food energy that you need to survive.

So you would be better off spreading out a large visible object and putting rocks ontop to stop it blowing away...hoping that rescuers, with a helicopter if you're lucky, will see it.

Then use the thick iron plate to help you dig a hole into the mountain side, as far as you are able, it'll be warmer in there than outside it!

Answer (score 1):

As you rotate the magnet, the eddy currents will create their own magnetic field, which will in turn act on the magnet.  The net result is that you will need to continually do work on the magnet in order to rotate the magnet.  In other words, you will have to expend energy.

According to the laws of conservation of energy, the amount of thermal energy you impart to the metal will be no greater than the food energy expended by your muscles to turn the magnet.  If you simply did vigorous calisthenics for the same amount of time, you would probably warm your body up by the same amount (if not more, since some heat energy that you would transfer to the metal would be lost to the environment before it got back to you.)  So using eddy currents is not a viable strategy for winter survival.